# Дубль письма клиенту Contact Form 7 WordPress

Tags: wordpress, contact-form7

Нужно чтобы после того, как пользователь оставляет заявку, ему на почту отправлялось письмо в определенном шаблоне по типа "Вы оставили заявку у нас на сайте, указали такие поля" и тд.. Как это можно реализовать ?

Answer (score 2):

В настройках Контактной формы плагина Contact Form 7 есть вкладка письмо, на которой вы задаете, куда отправить письмо. А в самом низу той же вкладки - галочка Письмо 2. Нажмите ее.

Используйте Письмо 2 для отправки сообщения клиенту.